# Is this minimalist?

Tags: composition, minimal-music

Can this piece of music be described as minimalist? Does it portray all of the appropriate characteristics?

[image: Minimalist 2.pdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this could be described as minimalist, due to its structure and approach - it's built on one short motif that is repeated many times and slowly varied, rather than utilizing longer phrases with functional harmony (cadences), or the contrast and variety typical of other 20th century styles.

However, I'm not going to make any kind of statement as to whether it's *good* minimalism...